# ASP.NET Core 8 & Blazor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, blazor, blazor-server-side

```
@page "/UpsertGame"
@using BlazorAppAuth.Models;
@using BlazorAppAuth.Data;
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager;
@inject DataContext _dataContext;
<h3>AddNewGames</h3>
<EditForm Model="videoGame" OnSubmit="Submit" FormName="Game">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>Title</label>
            <InputText @bind-Value="videoGame.Title" class="form-control form-control-sm"></InputText>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>Publisher</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="videoGame.Publisher" class="form-control form-control-sm" ></InputText>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>Released Year</label>
            <InputNumber @bind-Value="videoGame.ReleasedYear" class="form-control form-control-sm"></InputNumber>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark" name="Submit" />
    </div>
</div>
</EditForm>

@code {
    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    private VideoGame videoGame { get; set; } = new();
    private async Task Submit(){
        try
        {
            _dataContext.VideoGame.Add(videoGame);
           var resut= _dataContext.SaveChanges();
           if(resut==1)
                NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/UpsertGame");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

I use Blazor in .NET 8 static server side rendering. After saving data in the database, I want to redirect.

I check my code but not issue but I get a runtime error. If you any have a solution, please let me know.

I have one more case

```
if (UserCredentials.Username == "Ankesh" && UserCredentials.Password == "ank")
 {
     var claims = new List<Claim> {
               new Claim(type: ClaimTypes.Name,UserCredentials.Username),
             };
     var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
     var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
     await HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal);
     NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");


 }
```

In this if i use @rendermode InteractiveServer then httpContext retun null because it works in static render mode
now what i do in one case if i use @rendermode InteractiveServer then httpContext not working and another case if i not use then navigationManager gives error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIIVn.png)

I implement IHttpContextAccessor but it gives error issue not resolved.

```
 await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal);
in this line error is-Headers are read-only, response has already started.

@rendermode InteractiveServer
@inject IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor
```

in program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Comment: click "View Details" in the exception.. and show us the detailed error.

Answer (score 0):

Different .net7, you need to specify rendermode in blazor net8. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0 .Just add rendermode like following the navigation will work.

```
@page "/UpsertGame"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@inject IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor
...
await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal);
```

program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Comment: i add one more case

Comment: @Ankeshkumar you could access httpcontext using IhttpcontextAccessor in interactiveserver. I updated answer.

Comment: issue not resolved